# How can I make MyList iterable?

Tags: python, list, class, functional-programming, nodes

I want to create a class that behaves like a list. The challenge is doing it without using lists nor dictionaries. So far I've created a node class that goes like this:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.next = None
        self.last = None
        self.value = valor

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
```

And `MyList` class that's basically a chain of nodes, with a head node and a tail node. Thing is, I want to make it iterable so I can run a for with it. I  searched how iter and next works and came up with something like this:

```
class MyList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.head:
            if self.head.next:
                self.head = self.head.next
                return self.head.last
            aux = self.head
            self.head = None
            return aux
        raise StopIteration
```

It works but it obviously delete the data inside `MyList` so I can't use it again. Any advices on how to get the same results without messing up with the info inside the object?

Comment: You don't yield anything?

Comment: @RasmusDamgaardNielsen: `__next__` is supposed to return the value, not yield it.

Comment: Nope. I honestly don't get how generators really work. I've tried it a couple of times and ended with a loop.

Comment: @dm295 [In Python 3 it's `__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods).

Comment: @dm295 in python3 the syntax changed to __next__

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the iterator protocol only requires that [the container's `__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__) returns an iterator; you can also implement `__iter__` as a generator, rather than returning the instance itself:

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        yield node
        node = node.next
```

Comment: Finally someone is using `__iter__` as a generator function, defining a new class is such an overkill.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe ! The other answers are really helpful too but this is the simplest one :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "current" marker to your class to indicate the node currently pointed at by iteration.  Something like this:

```
class MyList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.current = self.head

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current is not None:
            it = self.current
            self.current = self.current.next
            return it
        raise StopIteration
```

Right now, your list doesn't distinguish between its head and its current iteration position, but these are two totally distinct concepts.

Of course, if you do it this way, all iterations over the same MyList will be "linked", so that if you do something like:

```
x = MyList(1, 2, 3, 4)
for item in x:
    print(x)
    if item == 2:
        break

for item in x:
    print(x)
```

Then the second iteration will pick up where the first left off.  If you don't want this behavior, you'll have to create a separate iterator class, and have `MyList.__iter__` return an instance of that rather than `self`.  If you return `self` from `__iter__`, then the object can't have multiple independent iterations going on, because the iteration state is stored in the object as the data being iterated.